# Are symmetric matrices a maximal subspace of conjugate-normal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $M$ denote the space of all complex $n\times n$ matrices. ($M$ is a complex vector space.)

Let $C\subseteq M$ be the set of all conjugate-normal matrices (i.e., matrices $A$ with $AA^*=\overline{A^*A}$).

Let $S\subseteq C$ denote all symmetric matrices. (Then $S$ is a subspace of $M$.)

Is there a subspace $X$ of $M$ such that $S\subseteq X\subseteq C$ and $X\neq S$?

Comment: $S$ is a real subspace of $M$ but not a complex subspace. Do you want $X$ to be a real or complex subspace?

Comment: I mean complex subspace everywhere. Why is $S$ not a complex subspace? (I see that Hermitean matrices are not a complex subspace, but I mean *symmetric*.)

Comment: Oh I see, my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the symmetric matrices are a maximal subspace in the conjugate-normal matrices.

Let $B$ be conjugate-normal and assume that $A+B\in C$ for all $A\in S$. Then 
\begin{align*}
0 & = (A+B)(A+B)^* - \overline{(A+B)^*(A+B)}
\\ & = (A+B)(\overline A + B^*) - (A + B^T)(\overline A + \overline B)
\\ & = AB^* + B\overline A - A\overline B - B^T\overline A.
\end{align*}
Let $B = [b_{ij}]_{i,j=1}^n$ and $A = E_{11}\in S$, the matrix unit, then above becomes
$$
0 = \left[\begin{array}{cccc} \overline{b_{11}} + b_{11} & \overline{b_{21}} & \cdots & \overline{b_{n1}} \\ b_{21} & 0 &&0
\\ \vdots&&&\vdots
\\ b_{n1} & 0 &\cdots&0 \end{array}\right] - \left[\begin{array}{cccc}   \overline{b_{11}} + b_{11} & \overline{b_{12}} & \cdots & \overline{b_{1n}} \\ b_{12} & 0 &&0
\\ \vdots&&&\vdots
\\ b_{1n} & 0 &\cdots&0\end{array}\right]
$$
which implies that $b_{1j} = b_{j1}$ for $2\leq j\leq n$. Repeat this process for $A = E_{ii}, 2\leq i\leq n$ to get that $B$ is symmetric.